# Javascript Date Function not working

Tags: javascript, html, date

I am trying to display the text 'Oct 09, 2012'.  Instead it is not running the function and is displaying a lot of unnessecary date text.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

You can play with my jsfiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/UP3fd/

Here is the code...

```
var myDate = new Date();

convertDate(myDate);

myDate.setFullYear(2012, 9, 9);

document.write(myDate);

function convertDate(d) {
    var day = d.getDate();
    if (day < 10) {
        day = "0" + day;
    }
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    var month = d.getMonth();
    var months=["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","June","July","Aug","Sep","Oct"," Nov","Dec"];
    var currentMonth = months[month];
    return (currentMonth + " " + day + ", " + year);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling your function before you set your date, and you are not saving/outputting the return value anywhere.

```
var myDate = new Date();

myDate.setFullYear(2012, 9, 9);

document.write( convertDate(myDate) );

function convertDate(d) {
    var day = d.getDate();
    if (day < 10) {
        day = "0" + day;
    }
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    var month = d.getMonth();
    var months=["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","June","July","Aug","Sep","Oct"," Nov","Dec"];
    var currentMonth = months[month];
    return (currentMonth + " " + day + ", " + year);
}
​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  var strDate =  addZero(d.getDate()) + "/" + addZero((d.getMonth() + 1))+ 
        "/" +d.getFullYear();
        alert("strDate :"+strDate)
        return strDate;
    }
    function addZero(i) {
        if (i < 10) {
            i = "0" + i;
        }
        return i;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct code:

```
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setFullYear(2012, 9, 9);
myDate = convertDate(myDate);
document.write(myDate);

[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the corrected code, this should return you what you are expecting.

```
var myDate = new Date();

myDate.setFullYear(2012, 9, 9);

var newDate = convertDate(myDate);

document.write(newDate);

function convertDate(d) {
    var day = d.getDate();
    if (day < 10) {
        day = "0" + day;
    }
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    var month = d.getMonth();
    var months=["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","June","July","Aug","Sep","Oct"," Nov","Dec"];
    var currentMonth = months[month];
    return (currentMonth + " " + day + ", " + year);

}
```